# Xamarin App edit info.plist Name cannot begin with the '<' character

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, info.plist

When I edit the info.plist on a Xamarin app, using the Mac OSX text editor, I run into this error when I try to build using the command line tool:

```
/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool --verbose build --f --target:Build --configuration:"Distribution|iPhone" --buildfile: {my project solution}
```

***{my project}/Info.plist : error: Error loading 'Info.plist': Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 59, position 2.***

I am actually trying to implement [this fix for the background image](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2014/09/iphone-6-and-6-plus-launch-images-for.html).

The only way that seems to be effective is to click on the info.plist in the Xamarin Studio, which does not provide a clear way to add other XML values.

Comment: You can try editing it with Xcode. Xcode probably has the best general plist file editor. You can right click -> open with -> Xcode from Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 1):

After a few months of facing this, I have the answer to my own question. I was also using an app called Plistbuddy during the build process. This actually re-arranged the XML on the Info.plist. So it was not a problem of the modificaiton, it was that the Subversion client was actually having a merge conflict and sticking the <<<<<<.mine text in the file itself.

```
Encountered unknown tag <<<<<< on line 59 
Error Reading File: ../Containers/Touch.Container/Info.plist
Encountered unknown tag <<<<<< on line 59
Error Reading File: ../Containers/Touch.Container/Info.plist
Xamarin Studio Build Tool
```

So the next time it built, the Info.plist that had been modified by the Plistbuddy now was in conflict with what was on the folder location. This was happenning on the Jenkins Build Mac that was updating and building.

I did two things
Change the SVN plugin on Jenkins to revert and update, not just update
Clear the Jenkins workspace after modifying the Info.Plist.

Either Xamarin Studio or XCode can be used to modify Info.plist. I would recommend XCode, since it offers up all the valid tags for the Info.plist XML. The Xamarin Studio will work with its current tags. I probably could have altered the file with a Mac text editor all this time with no problem if I know about the svn issue.

I plan to actually write a script with Plistbuddy anyway to update the version numbers before checkin.

Comment: I had the same problem but with git not svn. The lesson to everyone is that if there is any kind of mysterious build issue, do a 'git status' to and check that nothing funny is going on!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i opened info.plist in textEdit and removed the unwanted lines(e.g <<<<<<<<